# Add all rows after the first two rows in sql

Tags: sql

car    sum_of_solds rank

honda   150000       2

mazda   120000       3

tesla   180000       1

toyota  60000        4

I want to add all rows after the first two rows rank wise. So for in the above example, I want something like this:

car    sum_of_solds rank

tesla   150000      1

honda   120000      2

others  180000      others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a union query:

```sql
SELECT car, sum_of_solds, "rank"
FROM
(
    SELECT car, sum_of_solds, CAST("rank" AS varchar(10)) AS "rank", "rank" AS pos
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE "rank" <= 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'others', SUM(sum_of_solds), 'others', 3
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE "rank" > 2
) t
ORDER BY pos;
```

Comment: SELECT

car, sum_of_solds, rank FROM ranking WHERE rank <= 2

UNION ALL

SELECT 'others', SUM(sum_of_solds), 'others' FROM ranking WHERE rank > 2

ORDER BY rank

Comment: @TryingToCode ... that would only work on certain databases, such as MySQL.  You never told us your database, so I gave an answer which should work on most databases.